# AdMob Rewarded Video message on close video

Tags: android, admob

Implementing [AdMob Rewarded Video Ads for Android](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video) I see that when a user closes the ad before the reward is achieved the following message in the image is show. Does anyone know if it is possible to change that message? For example, `"You won't earn 30 coins"` instead of `You will lose your reward"`.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I am implementing Reward Videos. Can you please let me know how to get the time remaining to 30 sec. When I run the test ads, I see it is only 5sec.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither the SDK's APIs not the AdMob front-end allow you to customize this message.